# Serverless deploy two nextjs projects to a domain and subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, serverless, amazon-route53

I’m trying to deploy two separate nextjs projects to a subdomain and a domain (eg. app.domain.com & domain.com) to AWS.

I’ve currently got one project deployed to domain.com and [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) but I’m not sure how to deploy to app.domain.com from a second project.

It states I don’t own app.domain.com even though I have registered the domain in route53 and setup certificates for all 3 domains.

How would I go about deploying this via the[nextjs serverless plugin](https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/)

Comment: "It states" - what is "it"? Your application, Route53, ACM, ...?